# system.console NullPointerException

Tags: console, nullpointerexception

I know that this is a noobish error but I don't know how to fix it.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
Console kitty = System.console();
String username = kitty.readLine("Username: ");
}
```

> String username = kitty.readLine("Username: ");

produces the error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the username from the standard input, you could use this code:

```
try {
    System.out.print("Username: ");
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    String username = bufferedReader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Console returned by System.console() does not necessarily exist, that is why you get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 4):

From the javadoc :

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, **if any**.

If there is no console associated to the javadoc, the pointed line is the call of a method on a null object, hence the exception.

How do you launch your application ?

> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the
>   underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual
>   machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an
>   interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and
>   output streams then its console will exist and will typically be
>   connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine
>   was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for
>   example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have
>   a console.