# Console console = System.console(); gives null

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, console

I have to use `Console console = System.console();` to enter password via console in Eclipse, but it always
gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Why is it so?

or there is any other way available by which we can enter password via console which is not visible??

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963765/system-console-nullpointerexception

Comment: Hi, Yes I checked it, I want specifically password to be given as input which should not be visible in console when entered.

Comment: That question has an answer that explains clearly that System.console() can return null, so you can't rely on it always being non-null. Read the Javadoc for `System.console()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [java.io.Console.readPassword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Javadoc for `System.console()`, it can return null if there is no console allocated for the JVM. In fact this is often the case. So you can't rely on it being non-null.

When running your app from Eclipse, you *can* configure it to allocate a console. Open the launch configuration for your app, go to the **Common** tab, and near the bottom you'll find a checkbox option, "**Allocate console (necessary for input)**."

[image]

See @Jean-Baptiste's answer for hiding the user's typing in the console. But keep in mind that your app must gracefully deal with null from `Systemconsole()`.